# Can I enforce signing only for specific scripts or modules?

Tags: powershell, code-signing

I would like to turn on script signing, or some equivalent, against specific PowerShell modules which are being used by lots of scripts. The aim is to prevent use of modules that have unauthorized changes in them.

- I only need to do this on a small number of hosts.
- I **cannot** change the Execution Policy (i.e to turn on wholesale script signing).
- I do **not** need to do this for the non-module scripts.
- If necessary, I can make/mandate changes to the non-module scripts.
- This must work for scheduled scripts, i.e. be non-interactive.

I'm not looking for someone to design a full solution for me, but I'd like to know if there are ways to use "built-in" tools such as script signing to meet these requirements.

Comment: how about setting the execution policy with scope process from the calling scripts? PS: a silly idea, ignore me

Comment: Silly ideas welcome. Food for thought is needed!

Comment: Just a thought. write a customized "import-valid-module" function stores MD5/SHA1 hash of current modules you have, use this function validate psm1 file before you import. Then mandate all non-module script using this function?

Comment: Worth a thought. Module changes would mean updating all scripts if the hashes are kept local to the function, but I think I am prepared for that if necessary.

Comment: ...and putting the hashes in a database present a problem since I have SQL stuff modularized making that a catch-22.

Comment: Why not just [sign](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849819.aspx) the modules in question and [validate](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849805.aspx) the signatures in the scripts using the modules?

Comment: Sounds do-able, and probably not more than a couple of extra lines before loading the module... Potential answer here. ;-)

Comment: A little more work but what about a web service that access a backend database (RO) that will return the hash on any requested file... this will use built-in commandlets obviating the need for SQL modules.